# Как получить файлы из корня сервера?

Tags: php, apache, веб-сервер

Есть **index.php** расположенный по такому пути: /home/user/web/example.com/public_html/xxx/index.php

Этот index.php должен читать файлы из папки по такому пути: /home/user/моя/папка/находится/тут

Но сколько вариантов не пробовал, все время ошибка 500 и пишет "файл не находится в пределах допустимых путей"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте symlink и добавьте ссылку на папку внутрь области видимости. Поставить его можно таким образом:

```
ln -s /home/user/моя/папка/находится/тут /home/user/web/example.com/public_html/xxx/моя-папка
```

Если кратко:

```
ln -s /полный-путь-к-исходной-папке /полный-путь-к-папке-ссылке
```

По ssh можно такую же штуку будет сделать и на хостинге.

P.S.: Конфиг Apache для Virtual Host сайта, при котором этот вариант работает, у меня выглядит таким образом:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/www/sitefolder/wordpress"
  ServerName sitefolder.local

  <Directory "/Users/myuser/www/sitefolder/wordpress">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Согласно безопасности веб-сервер запрещает перемещение по директориям выше корня сайта. То есть сайт находится по следующему пути: /home/user/web/example.com/public_html/xxx/index.php , но прочитать содержание папок /home, или /home/user/моя/папка/ будет недоступно. index.php прочитать не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: В самом конфиге Apache на эту директорию стоит свойство `Options FollowSymLinks`? Добавил мой конфиг virtual host в ответ.